# Google map not loading properly iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

My application has Google Maps integration running smoothly for nearly a year now. However, about a week ago, the store version of our app started facing issues with Google maps without any app updates being pushed. Only the initial tiles(based on initial zoom level and area displayed) would load, with the subsequent tiles never loading. Using our bundle identifier in Google's sample app works as expected, with the map loading all tiles appropriately.

[image]

We are using google map SDK 2.5.0. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you uploaded your app after updating the google maps SDK?

Comment: Have you checked the Google API Dashboard to see if the error is there, it would explain the problem occurring without pushing any updates

Comment: @NiallKiddle we didnt get any error in Google API Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have been running this version for a year and without any explanation the map has stopped working. This tells me either API problems or potentially it has become outdated. I would recommend to update the SDK as Google have just released 2.6.0.

**Release notes** 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases

**Download**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start